# Напишите программу, которая будет эмулировать функциональность очереди

Tags: python

Нам поступают 3 команды:

```
add <число> – добавить в очередь число
pop – удалить из очереди число и напечатать его
head – вывести текущий элемент очереди
close – завершить программу

Sample Input:

add 5

add 10

head

pop

add 7

add 9

pop

pop

head

close

Sample Output:

5

5

10

7

9

Я ничего придумать не смог, может у вас будут какие-то подсказки?
```

Comment: вы уж определяйтесь, какие проблемы у вас с этой программой. Писать сюда тех задания не надо, для этого есть другие сайты

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

a = []
count = int(input('Количество числе для очереди: '))

for i in range(count):
    a.append(int(input('Введите числа в очередь: ')))
for j in a:
    print(j)
    time.sleep(2)
```